# No data on get request, postman

Tags: xml, postman

I want to do a get request to [charitycommission](http://apps.charitycommission.gov.uk/Showcharity/API/SearchCharitiesV1/Docs/dgGetCharitiesByKeyword.aspx) , but in response I don't get any relevant data. I am pretty sure that I do something wrong in my request, but I am not sure what.

**My get request:**

```
http://apps.charitycommission.gov.uk/Showcharity/API/SearchCharitiesV1/SearchCharitiesV1.asmx?APIKey=MyAPIKey&strSearch=happy
```

**For Headers:**

```
SOAPAction: "http://www.charitycommission.gov.uk/GetCharitiesByKeyword"

Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
```

Answer (score 0):

I fount out the solution. This is a `POST` request.

```
https://apps.charitycommission.gov.uk/Showcharity/API/SearchCharitiesV1/SearchCharitiesV1.asmx
```

On body I select `row` and from dropdown `XML`

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetCharitiesByKeyword xmlns="http://www.charitycommission.gov.uk/">
      <APIKey>MYAPIKEY</APIKey>
      <strSearch>happy</strSearch>
    </GetCharitiesByKeyword>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**Headers**

```
Content-Type  text/xml
```